# MongoDB POJO and inner/nested classes

Tags: java, mongodb, inner-classes, pojo

I've got a question regarding MongoDB Java driver and POJOs/serialization.
I'd like to build up my Java classes as they are represented in the MongoDB collection and then use the (new) POJO feature of MongoDB for fetching data. See: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/driver-async/getting-started/quick-start-pojo/ and http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/bson/pojos/

Right now this only works if I have two different classes, like

User.class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import org.bson.codecs.pojo.annotations.BsonId;
import org.bson.codecs.pojo.annotations.BsonProperty;

public class User {
  @BsonId
  @BsonProperty("_id")
  UUID id;
  private List<UserSession> sessions = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

UserSession.class

```
import java.time.Instant;

public class UserSession {
  Instant start;
  Instant end;
}
```

But as my collection looks more like the following…

```js
{
  _id: XYZ,
  sessions: {
    {start: XYZ, end: XYZ},
    {start: XYZ, end: XYZ},
    {start: XYZ, end: XYZ}
  }
}
```

… I'd like to have a class that looks like this:

User.class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.time.Instant;
import org.bson.codecs.pojo.annotations.BsonId;
import org.bson.codecs.pojo.annotations.BsonProperty;

public class User {
  @BsonId
  @BsonProperty("_id")
  UUID id;
  private List<Session> sessions = new ArrayList<>();

  public class Session {
    Instant start;
    Instant end;
  }
}
```

This makes sense as every unique sessions belongs directly to a user and with being a nested class I'd be able to access fields of the parent User object from within the Session object.

The problem is that the Java driver now complains about not having an empty/no arguments constructor for my Session class ("By default all POJOs must include a public or protected, empty, no arguments, constructor.").

My CodecProvider is like following:

```java
CodecProvider codecProvider = PojoCodecProvider.builder()
    .register(User.class, User.Session.class);
```

Anyone here having an idea how to solve this issue?

Really appreciate your help!

Thanks a lot!

*Side note: The code snippets above are just short examples how my code kinda looks like. They are not the full code I'm using so there might be syntax errors in it.*

Comment: Maybe you have _simplified_ too much: Both your classes, `User` and `Session` do have a public no-argument constructor!

Comment: Of course I can do `new User()` - but I think MongoDBs POJO implementation is looking for something like `new Session()`, but it needs to handle it like `User user = new User(); User.Session session = user.new Session()` or am I wrong?

Comment: Ah! I overlooked that. You made an _inner_ class, not a _static nested_ class. So simply declare your class as `public static class Session ...`.

Comment: But then it isn't possible to access fields from my parent object, like the `id` of the `User` from within my `Session` object, right?

Comment: Why should that be impossible? I fear, your question is unclear. Please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: As soon as I have a static class, I cannot do thinks like `this.User.id` from within my `Session` for getting the `UUID` of the parent `User`. This is only possible with non static classes.